# como puedo randomizar los siguientes resultado

Tags: php, javascript, html, script

quiero que el siguiente codigo me arroje numeros automaticos pero en random yo poniendole un minimo y un maximo?

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Numeros Aleatorios</title>
    </head>
    <body>
 
<div class="xbox-row xbox-clearfix xbox-type-number xbox-row-id-post_views_count " data-row-level="1" data-field-id="post_views_count" data-field-type="number">
    
    <div class="xbox-label">
        <label for="post_views_count" class="xbox-element-label">Views</label>
    </div>
    <div class="xbox-content xbox-clearfix">
        
    <div class="xbox-field xbox-field-id-post_views_count xbox-has-unit xbox-show-spinner xbox-has-spinner " data-default="">
        <input type="text" name="post_views_count" id="post_views_count" value="5152" class="xbox-element xbox-element-text" data-min="0" data-max="null" data-step="1" data-precision="0">
        <div class="xbox-unit xbox-noselect">
            views
            <a href="javascript:;" class="xbox-spinner-control" data-spin="up">
                <i class="xbox-icon xbox-icon-caret-up">
                    
                </i>
                &gt;
                </a>
            
            <a href="javascript:;" class="xbox-spinner-control" data-spin="down">
                <i class="xbox-icon xbox-icon-caret-down">
                    
                </i>
                &gt;
                </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="xbox-row xbox-clearfix xbox-type-number xbox-row-id-likes_count " data-row-level="1" data-field-id="likes_count" data-field-type="number">
    
    <div class="xbox-label">
        <label for="likes_count" class="xbox-element-label">Likes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="xbox-content xbox-clearfix">
        
        <div class="xbox-field xbox-field-id-likes_count xbox-has-unit xbox-show-spinner xbox-has-spinner " data-default=""><input type="text" name="likes_count" id="likes_count" value="713" class="xbox-element xbox-element-text" data-min="0" data-max="null" data-step="1" data-precision="0">
            <div class="xbox-unit xbox-noselect">
                <i class="xbox-icon xbox-icon-thumbs-up">
                
                </i>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="xbox-spinner-control" data-spin="up">
                    <i class="xbox-icon xbox-icon-caret-up">
                    
                    </i>
                    &gt;
                </a><a href="javascript:;" class="xbox-spinner-control" data-spin="down">
                <i class="xbox-icon xbox-icon-caret-down">
                
                </i>
                &gt;
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="xbox-row xbox-clearfix xbox-type-number xbox-row-id-dislikes_count " data-row-level="1" data-field-id="dislikes_count" data-field-type="number">
    
    <div class="xbox-label">
        <label for="dislikes_count" class="xbox-element-label">Dislikes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="xbox-content xbox-clearfix">
        
        <div class="xbox-field xbox-field-id-dislikes_count xbox-has-unit xbox-show-spinner xbox-has-spinner " data-default=""><input type="text" name="dislikes_count" id="dislikes_count" value="72" class="xbox-element xbox-element-text" data-min="0" data-max="null" data-step="1" data-precision="0">
            <div class="xbox-unit xbox-noselect">
                <i class="xbox-icon xbox-icon-thumbs-down">
                
                </i>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="xbox-spinner-control" data-spin="up">
                    <i class="xbox-icon xbox-icon-caret-up">
                    
                    </i>
                    &gt;
                </a><a href="javascript:;" class="xbox-spinner-control" data-spin="down">
                <i class="xbox-icon xbox-icon-caret-down">
                
                </i>
                &gt;
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  
    
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: En php o javascript? porque este codigo no hace nada de eso y no intentaste nada... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);` obtienes un número aleatorio del 1 al 100.

Ya sólo tendrías crear 3 y colocarlos como el valor de los inputs.

```js
//Selecciona tus inpus usando queries al dom, en este caso seleccionaremos todos
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

console.log({inputs});

//Asigna el value del input a un valor númerico random entre 1 y 100, por ejemplo.
inputs.forEach(i=>{
i.value =Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Numeros Aleatorios</title>
    </head>
    <body>
 
<div class="xbox-row xbox-clearfix xbox-type-number xbox-row-id-post_views_count " data-row-level="1" data-field-id="post_views_count" data-field-type="number">
    
    <div class="xbox-label">
        <label for="post_views_count" class="xbox-element-label">Views</label>
    </div>
    <div class="xbox-content xbox-clearfix">
        
    <div class="xbox-field xbox-field-id-post_views_count xbox-has-unit xbox-show-spinner xbox-has-spinner " data-default="">
        <input type="text" name="post_views_count" id="post_views_count" value="5152" class="xbox-element xbox-element-text" data-min="0" data-max="null" data-step="1" data-precision="0">
        <div class="xbox-unit xbox-noselect">
            views
            <a href="javascript:;" class="xbox-spinner-control" data-spin="up">
                <i class="xbox-icon xbox-icon-caret-up">
                    
                </i>
                &gt;
                </a>
            
            <a href="javascript:;" class="xbox-spinner-control" data-spin="down">
                <i class="xbox-icon xbox-icon-caret-down">
                    
                </i>
                &gt;
                </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="xbox-row xbox-clearfix xbox-type-number xbox-row-id-likes_count " data-row-level="1" data-field-id="likes_count" data-field-type="number">
    
    <div class="xbox-label">
        <label for="likes_count" class="xbox-element-label">Likes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="xbox-content xbox-clearfix">
        
        <div class="xbox-field xbox-field-id-likes_count xbox-has-unit xbox-show-spinner xbox-has-spinner " data-default=""><input type="text" name="likes_count" id="likes_count" value="713" class="xbox-element xbox-element-text" data-min="0" data-max="null" data-step="1" data-precision="0">
            <div class="xbox-unit xbox-noselect">
                <i class="xbox-icon xbox-icon-thumbs-up">
                
                </i>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="xbox-spinner-control" data-spin="up">
                    <i class="xbox-icon xbox-icon-caret-up">
                    
                    </i>
                    &gt;
                </a><a href="javascript:;" class="xbox-spinner-control" data-spin="down">
                <i class="xbox-icon xbox-icon-caret-down">
                
                </i>
                &gt;
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="xbox-row xbox-clearfix xbox-type-number xbox-row-id-dislikes_count " data-row-level="1" data-field-id="dislikes_count" data-field-type="number">
    
    <div class="xbox-label">
        <label for="dislikes_count" class="xbox-element-label">Dislikes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="xbox-content xbox-clearfix">
        
        <div class="xbox-field xbox-field-id-dislikes_count xbox-has-unit xbox-show-spinner xbox-has-spinner " data-default=""><input type="text" name="dislikes_count" id="dislikes_count" value="72" class="xbox-element xbox-element-text" data-min="0" data-max="null" data-step="1" data-precision="0">
            <div class="xbox-unit xbox-noselect">
                <i class="xbox-icon xbox-icon-thumbs-down">
                
                </i>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="xbox-spinner-control" data-spin="up">
                    <i class="xbox-icon xbox-icon-caret-up">
                    
                    </i>
                    &gt;
                </a><a href="javascript:;" class="xbox-spinner-control" data-spin="down">
                <i class="xbox-icon xbox-icon-caret-down">
                
                </i>
                &gt;
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  
    
    </body>
    
</html>
 EjecutarVolver a publicación
```

Comment: ahi es que estoy perdido... los inputs.

Comment: Ya te he extendido la respuesta para que se modifique el valor de los inputs.

Comment: hugomosh, te agradezco bastante... pero no logro seleccionar las inputs usando querys, es que a cada input le quiero poner un minimo y maximo diferente. Ejemplo: a Views de (3500 a 30000) a Likes de (450 a 3000) y a Dislikes de (70 a 300), no se si me entiendas... pero gracias de todos modos, me haz ayudado mucho